# `sudo apt-get -f install` fails everytime

Tags: linux, apt, sudo

This command `sudo apt-get -f install` fails every time I try to run it.

[image]

Comment: It is hard to understand what exactly goes wrong according to this screenshot. Try to run `strace apt-get -f install` . Also try to look at `/var/log/apt/term.log`

Comment: try #apt-get update" and #dpkg-reconfigure--force" first and then try to install.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to clean the package cache by issuing:

```
$ sudo apt-cache clean
```

And then a `$ sudo apt-get update`, just in case.